# Python Seek Function with an offset exceeding the file size

Tags: python, file-handling, seek, file-pointer

I am trying to understand how the seek function in python file handling works. The syntax of this function is *seek(offset, whence)*. The parameter 'whence' is like a point of reference with possible values 0,1 and 2 referring to start of the file, current position of the pointer (return value of *'tell'* function) and end of the file respectively. Consider the file is being opened in binary red mode and the length of the file is 22. Consider three programs where I try to move the pointer to a position exceeding the file size. Logically the program should either return an exception or stop at the end of file. But the output is different where the pointer exceeds the boundary and when trying to read from that position the output is an empty string. Explain how it works.

I tried these three programs and was confused with the output.

## Program 1

whence value is 0 and offset is greater than size of file

```
fp = open('sample.txt', 'rb')
print('Current position of pointer is', fp.tell())
size_of_file = len(fp.read())
print('Size of the file is', size_of_file)
fp.seek(0,0) #Bringing back the pointer to start of file
fp.seek(size_of_file + 1, 0)
print('Current position of pointer is', fp.tell())
print(fp.read())
```

The output is

```
Current position of pointer is 0
Size of the file is 22
Current position of pointer is 23
b''
```

## Program 2

whence value is 1 and offset is greater than the remaining read size of the file

```
fp = open('sample.txt', 'rb')
print('Current position of pointer is', fp.tell())
size_of_file = len(fp.read())
print('Size of the file is', size_of_file)
fp.seek(size_of_file // 2,1) #Bringing the pointer to middle of file
fp.seek((size_of_file // 2) + 1, 1)
print('Current position of pointer is', fp.tell())
print(fp.read())
```

The output is

```
Current position of pointer is 0
Size of the file is 22
Current position of pointer is 45
b''
```

## Program 3

whence value is 2 and offset is a positive number

```
fp = open('sample.txt', 'rb')
print('Current position of pointer is', fp.tell())
size_of_file = len(fp.read())
print('Size of the file is', size_of_file)
fp.seek(0,2) #Bringing the pointer to end of file
fp.seek(1, 2)
print('Current position of pointer is', fp.tell())
print(fp.read())
```

The output is

```
Current position of pointer is 0
Size of the file is 22
Current position of pointer is 23
b''
```

Explain how the pointer moves?

Comment: On many Unix-type systems, it is perfectly legal to seek past the end of the file, and the length of the file will be extended accordingly.  The empty space will be filled with zeros.

Comment: If you seek far enough past the end of the file to skip entire disk blocks' worth of data, you end up with a *sparse file* - the skipped blocks aren't physically written to disk at all (but still read as zeroes).

Comment: Note that what @jasonharper wrote is true for most Unix OS and filesystems but not all. There is no guarantee you'll get a sparse file unless you have verified the specific OS and filesystem support it. A lot of hash based databases (such as `dbm`) rely on sparse file behavior to write data at wildly separated offsets without actually allocating filesystem blocks between those offsets. So a simple `ls -l` might show a huge logical size while the physical size is much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

when you attempt to seek beyond the end of a file in Python, the file pointer is positioned at the end of the file. Subsequent read operations from this position return an empty string, indicating the end of the file has been reached. This behavior allows for seeking beyond the end of the file without raising exceptions, providing flexibility in file manipulation.

Comment: This is technically correct but misses the real point which is to support the behavior of filesystems on typical Unix like OS's. Specifically, the ability to extend the length of a file quickly and often in a space efficient manner known as a "sparse file" where the logical size is greater than the physical size (that is, actual space consumed in the filesystem).